Podman proxy bypass for specific repositories
I have got Podman running within WSL on a Windows host which is behind a company proxy. I have set up HTTP_PROXY env variable so the pull/push commands work through the company proxy when working with 3rd party repositories (available on the internet).
However at the same time I need to be able to pull/push to a company repository within the company network. These requests cannot go through the proxy, the proxy has to be bypassed for this specific repository.
Podman seems to ignore the NO_PROXY env variable. Is there a way to bypass proxy only for specific repositories?
